# Get List of All Emacs Buffers

Tags: list, emacs, buffer

How do I get a list of all buffers in Emacs? I then want to iterate this list using `dolist` or `mapcar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `(buffer-list &optional frame)`:

Return a list of all existing live buffers.
If the optional arg FRAME is a frame, we return the buffer list in the
proper order for that frame: the buffers show in FRAME come first,
followed by the rest of the buffers.

Answer (score -1):

`(list-buffers)` and work from there?

Comment: `list-buffers` would be great if the original question mentioned eyes, keyboard and mouse instead of `dolist` and `mapcar`.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko list-buffers has source, one can look at and see how it works.

Comment: True: looking at it source (found with `describe-function`) leads finally to `(list-buffers--refresh buffer-list old-buffer)`, of which `buffer-list` is the right function.